# Hadoop encryption zone remote exception

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs

I am trying to create an encryption zone in an empty directory /enc_zone2. This is the command i am using

```
hdfs crypto -createZone -keyName key2 -path /enc_zone2
```

When i try to see the list of keys using

```
hadoop key list -metadata
```

i am able to see the metadata for key2.

But , the error i am getting when creating a zone is

```
"RemoteException: Can't create an encryption zone for /temp since no key provider is available."
```

However, the KMS server has started and running in port 16000. Also, the command to list keys and to list zones are working which means the keyprovider is working.

This is the error log of name node

```
Can't create an encryption zone for /enc_zone2 since no key provider is available.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.createEncryptionZone(FSNamesystem.java:7981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.createEncryptionZone(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1833)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.createEncryptionZone(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:1352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045).
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Rajkamal in my case even I was facing the same issue, but after adding below  properties in hdfs-site.xml. I was able to create encrytpion zone.

```
<property>
 <name>dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri</name>
 <value>kms://http@localhost:16000/kms</value>
</property>
```

After adding property please restart kms server and hadoop services.

Try and verify may be this solution works in your case.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks